# Using c# to convert string to a dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I get the following string from a logging service:

```
[("Browser": "Chrome73 (v 73.0)"), ("UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"), ("Languages": ["nb-NO", "nb;q=0.9", "no;q=0.8", "nn;q=0.7", "en-US;q=0.6", "en;q=0.5"]), ("UserClaim-1-http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin"), ("SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e"), ("Cookie-__RequestVerificationToken": "9MJm_A4agsgbe4c_JtAePFnfMLBEgnkc0XhROfDFVd6291SUGtLPAqprsGHBcJw9JDRde6UR_1jHY_Hr4oKi4OZzuUDXqAA6IfeEtr9sxVI1"), ("Cookie-.ASPXAUTH": "AA23B2B1A5C428BFB60E32EA5A78A7D5016D7586F88548C012A1C2C2EB2A34D40A959B43680BCCE9923F1890017F59A3A82E6C1121AF50CF226D638FBCBC40F2D8E2FE4C945B44CC7572717D56C71FCC0B7B285A0EB5379370ADC6BE970E6438"), ("Cookie-ASP.NET_SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e"), ("Info-FamilyId": 21267), ("Info-LoggedInUserID": 1), ("Info-MainConsultantUserId": 3)]
```

And I would like to turn it into a dictionary. I should be a simple task I thought, but I have been trying to parse the string in various ways without success. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have been trying to use:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(the_string_above);
```

I get the exception:
**Unexpected character encountered while parsing value. (.Path '', line 1, position 1)**

The format is not valid JSON as pointed out in the comments so the question then is how can I parse the text...

Comment: Don´t parse JSON yourself, use a JSON-parser, e.g. Newtonsoft.

Comment: What do you mean by an array of dictionaries? This looks like an array of key-value tuples, so one dictionary?

Comment: you should deserialize this with a suitable deserializer instead of tring to do it yourself rely on tested and approved functionality. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: *I should be a simple task I thought, but I have been trying to parse the string in various ways without success* Show us what you got so far.

Comment: Looking at your example are you just trying to turn this into a single dictionary?

Comment: Turning the string into a single sictionary would be correct. I have edited the text...

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/ 
Paste your string & try to fix 
I think just some format error !?

Comment: The format is not valid JSON so I guess the question really is how to parse this string correctly...

Comment: Your JSON should look like this:
{
 "Browser": "Chrome73 (v 73.0)",
 "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
  ...
}

Comment: I know the format should be different, but I have to work with what I get from the logging service...

Comment: @Liknes I have tried a regex solution for this. Please see working demo and let me know if it suffices: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u1YbBK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my attempt is towards a `Regex` based solution, but a JSON solution would be better and more efficient. I have prepared a sample regex based solution for your string.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string str = "[(\"Browser\": \"Chrome73 (v 73.0)\"), (\"UserAgent\": \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"), (\"Languages\": [\"nb-NO\", \"nb;q=0.9\", \"no;q=0.8\", \"nn;q=0.7\", \"en-US;q=0.6\", \"en;q=0.5\"]), (\"UserClaim-1-http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role\": \"Admin\"), (\"SessionId\": \"hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e\"), (\"Cookie-__RequestVerificationToken\": \"9MJm_A4agsgbe4c_JtAePFnfMLBEgnkc0XhROfDFVd6291SUGtLPAqprsGHBcJw9JDRde6UR_1jHY_Hr4oKi4OZzuUDXqAA6IfeEtr9sxVI1\"), (\"Cookie-.ASPXAUTH\": \"AA23B2B1A5C428BFB60E32EA5A78A7D5016D7586F88548C012A1C2C2EB2A34D40A959B43680BCCE9923F1890017F59A3A82E6C1121AF50CF226D638FBCBC40F2D8E2FE4C945B44CC7572717D56C71FCC0B7B285A0EB5379370ADC6BE970E6438\"), (\"Cookie-ASP.NET_SessionId\": \"hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e\"), (\"Info-FamilyId\": 21267), (\"Info-LoggedInUserID\": 1), (\"Info-MainConsultantUserId\": 3)]";
         showMatch(str, @"(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)[,\]])");
    }

     private static void showMatch(string text, string expr) {
         MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);

         foreach (Match m in mc) {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
         }
      }
}
```

This will output:

```
"Browser": "Chrome73 (v 73.0)"
"UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
"Languages": ["nb-NO", "nb;q=0.9", "no;q=0.8", "nn;q=0.7", "en-US;q=0.6", "en;q=0.5"]
"UserClaim-1-http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin"
"SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e"
"Cookie-__RequestVerificationToken": "9MJm_A4agsgbe4c_JtAePFnfMLBEgnkc0XhROfDFVd6291SUGtLPAqprsGHBcJw9JDRde6UR_1jHY_Hr4oKi4OZzuUDXqAA6IfeEtr9sxVI1"
"Cookie-.ASPXAUTH": "AA23B2B1A5C428BFB60E32EA5A78A7D5016D7586F88548C012A1C2C2EB2A34D40A959B43680BCCE9923F1890017F59A3A82E6C1121AF50CF226D638FBCBC40F2D8E2FE4C945B44CC7572717D56C71FCC0B7B285A0EB5379370ADC6BE970E6438"
"Cookie-ASP.NET_SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e"
"Info-FamilyId": 21267
"Info-LoggedInUserID": 1
"Info-MainConsultantUserId": 3
```

Working Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u1YbBK

Regex used: `(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)[,\]])`

Explanation:

1. Positive Lookbehind (?<=(): `\(` matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)
2. 1st Capturing Group (.*?): `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators) and `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
3. Positive Lookahead (?=)[,]]): `\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive) and in `[,\]]` `,` matches the character `,` literally (case sensitive) and `\]` matches the character `]` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks! The output of this solution does it for me, and as far as I can see it works perfectly for all the logged data in the database! I know this solution is not answering my question 100%, but helped me to solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
[{"Browser": "Chrome73 {v 73.0}"}, {"UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 {Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64} AppleWebKit/537.36 {KHTML, like Gecko} Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"}, {"Languages": ["nb-NO", "nb;q=0.9", "no;q=0.8", "nn;q=0.7", "en-US;q=0.6", "en;q=0.5"]}, {"UserClaim-1-http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin"}, {"SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e"}, {"Cookie-__RequestVerificationToken": "9MJm_A4agsgbe4c_JtAePFnfMLBEgnkc0XhROfDFVd6291SUGtLPAqprsGHBcJw9JDRde6UR_1jHY_Hr4oKi4OZzuUDXqAA6IfeEtr9sxVI1"}, {"Cookie-.ASPXAUTH": "AA23B2B1A5C428BFB60E32EA5A78A7D5016D7586F88548C012A1C2C2EB2A34D40A959B43680BCCE9923F1890017F59A3A82E6C1121AF50CF226D638FBCBC40F2D8E2FE4C945B44CC7572717D56C71FCC0B7B285A0EB5379370ADC6BE970E6438"}, {"Cookie-ASP.NET_SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e"}, {"Info-FamilyId": 21267}, {"Info-LoggedInUserID": 1}, {"Info-MainConsultantUserId": 3}]
```

It work find, Just replace '(' to '{' & ')' to '}'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
You can see how is json work , maybe you lose something ,
And use http://json.parser.online.fr/ to try your json string .

Comment: Thanks! Your simple solution actually works with all the data I have in the database, but it kind of messes up the data a bit. i.e Chrome73 (v 73.0) turns into Chrome73 {v 73.0}

Answer (score 1):

An example conversion with the Regex by Rahul Sharma:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Solution {

    public class Parser {

        public static Dictionary<string,string> parseLoggingInformation(string info) {

            Dictionary<string, string> ret = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(info, @"(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)[,\]])");
            foreach (Match m in mc) {
                string val = m.ToString();
                string[] vals;
                try {
                    vals = val.Split(new string[] { "\": \"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    string tmp = vals[1];
                } catch (Exception) {
                    vals = val.Split(new string[] { "\": " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                }
                string left = vals[0];
                string right = vals[1];
                ret.Add(left.Substring(1, left.Length - 1), right.Substring(0, right.Length - 1));
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public static void Main(String[] args) {
            GC.Collect();
            Dictionary<string, string> loggingData = parseLoggingInformation("[(\"Browser\": \"Chrome73 (v 73.0)\"), (\"UserAgent\": \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"), (\"Languages\": [\"nb-NO\", \"nb;q=0.9\", \"no;q=0.8\", \"nn;q=0.7\", \"en-US;q=0.6\", \"en;q=0.5\"]), (\"UserClaim-1-http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role\": \"Admin\"), (\"SessionId\": \"hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e\"), (\"Cookie-__RequestVerificationToken\": \"9MJm_A4agsgbe4c_JtAePFnfMLBEgnkc0XhROfDFVd6291SUGtLPAqprsGHBcJw9JDRde6UR_1jHY_Hr4oKi4OZzuUDXqAA6IfeEtr9sxVI1\"), (\"Cookie-.ASPXAUTH\": \"AA23B2B1A5C428BFB60E32EA5A78A7D5016D7586F88548C012A1C2C2EB2A34D40A959B43680BCCE9923F1890017F59A3A82E6C1121AF50CF226D638FBCBC40F2D8E2FE4C945B44CC7572717D56C71FCC0B7B285A0EB5379370ADC6BE970E6438\"), (\"Cookie-ASP.NET_SessionId\": \"hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e\"), (\"Info-FamilyId\": 21267), (\"Info-LoggedInUserID\": 1), (\"Info-MainConsultantUserId\": 3)]");
        }
    }
}
```

It saves the gathered data in a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this thing looks *almost* like a JSON dictionary, only that

1. It's an array `[]` instead of a dictionary `{}`.
2. Key-value tuples are bracketed inside `()`.

So the laziest idea is to change the outside brackets into `{}`, which is trivial, and then get rid of the unnecessary `()` brackets. You'll end up with a valid JSON that can be directly parsed with `Newtonsoft.Json` or other parser of your choice.

To parse the thing, we will greedily escape all `()` brackets in quotes and ignore all the rest.

```
public static string LogToJson(string inputString)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder("{");
    var escaping = false;

    for (var index = 1 /* Skipping opening [ */ ; index < inputString.Length; ++index)
    {
        var @char = inputString[index];
        switch (@char)
        {
            case '(' when !escaping:
            case ')' when !escaping:
                break;
            case '"':
                escaping ^= true;
                builder.Append(@char);
                break;
            default:
                builder.Append(@char);
                break;
        }
    }

    builder.Length--; // Remove the final ]
    builder.Append("}");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Please note that this completely omits error handling and assumes the `inputString` is always correct. Thus it gurantees a correct JSON if and only if the input format was a correct json after removing all unescaped `()` brackets.

For your example string the output is:

```
{"Browser": "Chrome73 (v 73.0)", "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36", "Languages": ["nb-NO", "nb;q=0.9", "no;q=0.8", "nn;q=0.7", "en-US;q=0.6", "en;q=0.5"], "UserClaim-1-http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin", "SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e", "Cookie-__RequestVerificationToken": "9MJm_A4agsgbe4c_JtAePFnfMLBEgnkc0XhROfDFVd6291SUGtLPAqprsGHBcJw9JDRde6UR_1jHY_Hr4oKi4OZzuUDXqAA6IfeEtr9sxVI1", "Cookie-.ASPXAUTH": "AA23B2B1A5C428BFB60E32EA5A78A7D5016D7586F88548C012A1C2C2EB2A34D40A959B43680BCCE9923F1890017F59A3A82E6C1121AF50CF226D638FBCBC40F2D8E2FE4C945B44CC7572717D56C71FCC0B7B285A0EB5379370ADC6BE970E6438", "Cookie-ASP.NET_SessionId": "hhaztuwfpyuobfslljuy4z4e", "Info-FamilyId": 21267, "Info-LoggedInUserID": 1, "Info-MainConsultantUserId": 3}
```

Comment: This isn't converting the string to a dictionary, which I think is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: As I said, we're converting the string to JSON so that it can be parsed using any standard JSON parser. That part is rather trivial.